# mysql select data when one field may or may not contain values

Tags: php, mysql

Have a MYSQL look  up table that returns the points received for a certain place(P) among a number of finishers(N), with a variety of formats(points_id).  Different point structures are used for different events.   Some times the points awarded depend on the number of finishers(N)  Sometimes they don't.
Here is a short version of the table, with two sample structures.
points_id -1 the points depends on N  Point_id -2 the points don't.

points

```
       points_id |   P   |   N   | points |
           1     |   1   |   3   |   90   |
           1     |   1   |   2   |   85   |
           1     |   1   |   1   |   80   |
           1     |   2   |   3   |   60   |
           1     |   2   |   2   |   50   |
           1     |   3   |   3   |   30   |
           3     |   1   |       |  100   |
           3     |   2   |       |   90   |
           3     |   3   |       |   80   |
           3     |   3   |       |   70   |
```

So my question:
1)  is there a way to put the wildcard in the table data.
eg if the N column that shows blank had a % in it
and I did this query.

```
SELECT points from t1 WHERE points_id=3 and P=3 and N=2
```

It  would return 96??
PS I know this doesn't work but is shows my idea.

2)  I want it to be fast, may put it in a procedure to use in larger queries. I am guessing unless there is a very simple way to do what I show above. the fastest method will be to have rows for all of the different N's in the points_id =3 case.  Is that true?

Comment: How would it return a result like "96??"? I have no data in sample table and your query doesn't have LIKE operation.That query cannot result such a result most probably

Comment: I would just change the query: `SELECT points from t1 WHERE points_id=3 and P=3 and (N=2 OR N IS NULL)`

Comment: Sorry about the 96  should have been 80, didn't have enough points to  post the table as an image.

Comment: Duh (Or IS NULL) use the NULL as a wild card.  I think that will work great.  Thanks,

Comment: Well thanks for the easy solution. But is does beg one additional question.
If I use Null the way you describe essentially as the wildcard, I can't have that column be in my primary key set.  My data then has a lot of duplicate primary keys.
I see two ways out;

1)  Create a record id  make that the primary,  create another key set to improve speed.

2) Use another character in that field as the wildcard.  Eg 0   the Where becomes AND (N=2 or N=0).

Anyone have a view on which is the best way.
Dave

Comment: I agree. Use 0 or NULL as the "wildcard". If 0 is a valid number, then you could make the column signed and use -1.

Comment: You mean it should return 80 but I think 70 is also similar to that

Comment: so that should be in result or not? also specify data type of field `N`

Answer (score 0):

You might consider UNION ALL:

```
SELECT points from t1 WHERE points_id=3 AND P=3
UNION ALL
SELECT points from t1 WHERE points_id=3 AND N=2
```

This will get the results regardless if P=3 or N=2. I copied your database schema and tried this, and it produced:

```
points
------
80
70
```

If you do want this to be fast with a large amount of data--you'll really want to have an index and/or primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT points from t1 WHERE points_id=3 and P=3 and (N=2 OR (IFNULL(N,'')='')) 
// dataType of N varchar
SELECT points from t1 WHERE points_id=3 and P=3 and (N=2 OR (IFNULL(N,0)=0))
//  dataType of N numeric type
```

**Let me know if there is any change or am getting you wrong**